# Python Pyqt4 QListWidget

Tags: python, indexing, pyqt4, qlistwidget

I am working on python plugins.I designed my forms using **PYQT4** designer.

1)I used QListWidgets,wherein m listing some values into the same as shown below:

[image]

The name of my **QListWidget** is **fieldsList_4**.Now, the "**ACO_43_HORSE_01**" is parent of 2,1,7 and 8. When user will select either one of the value from 2,1 ,7 and 8,i want to retrieve their  respective parent.In this case ,it is **ACO_43_HORSE_01**.

I thought of doing so using indexes of selected values from QListWidget.I tried

```
idx=self.fieldsList_4.index(sel_stratum)
```

but no success.How do i find index of selected item of **QListWidget**??

2)When i select items from QListWidget ,they are highlighted as shown below:

[image]

but when i click on some other  controls on the form ,they become like this:

[image]

so,i wanted the selected values from QListWidget to remain highlighted .How do i do it??

Thanx in advance.